# SDL_RenderFillRect doesn't display anything

Tags: c++14, sdl-2

OK, my problem is that I am trying to recreate a snake game clone, but at the very begginning I got a problem displaying a simple rectangle at the center of the screen. I don't know what is the problem I used the same code as I used in my pong clone to display the paddle's but here it's not working. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

bool run = true;

class Game
{
    private:
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* render = NULL;
    SDL_Rect snake;

    public:
    Game()
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Snake Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 800, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
        render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
        snake.x = 400;
        snake.y = 400;
        snake.w = 50;
        snake.h = 50;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(render);
        SDL_RenderPresent(render);
    }

    void Event()
    {
        SDL_Event close;
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&close)){
            if(close.type == SDL_QUIT){
                run = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void InitSnake()
    {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(render, &snake);
        SDL_RenderClear(render);
        SDL_RenderPresent(render);
    }
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    Game game;
    while(run)
    {
        game.Event();
        game.InitSnake();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render, 255, 255, 255, 255);
SDL_RenderFillRect(render, &snake);
SDL_RenderClear(render);
SDL_RenderPresent(render);
```

This code sets colour to white, draws 'snake' rectangle, then fills entire screen (clear) with current colour. What usual display function does is: set clear colour, clear, display all game things, present.

Also your `Event` function uses `if(SDL_PollEvent(&close))`, but if you have multiple events accumulated between frames - you still process only one each frame, which will result in ever increasing lag and eventually dropping events when queue will become too big. Use `while` to read all events each frame instead.

Comment: I would understand if the screen was becoming white, but it remains black even if the way I put the code is wrong it should at least color something white and it still doesn't display the reactangle

Comment: It sure is white when I run it, as it should be.

Comment: well for me it isn't the screen remains black

Answer (score -1):

OK, how stupid, I just created a new project and tried again and now it's displaying everything I need with the same code, nice.